# Links Web Part in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, custom, links-list

I am trying to use SP 2010's links web part on my page. I want to show only Titles of my hyperlinks but under different headers. For Example i want to display 3 headers and under each header there are links to urls or documents. How this can be done?

I am looking for something like

[image]

All items are external links.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Summary Link Web Part.

Create three groups with the correct header names. Reorder the links to go under the correct headers.

[image: Summary Links Web Part with groups and links]

If you're using the "My Links" on MySite, it's almost the same approach. There's groups for the links there as well, which will show as headers in the web part

[image]

Comment: No My site is not a publishing site, I am using "Links" web part not Summary Link web part.

Comment: Okay, I would add that information to your question

Comment: I have updated the question with the "My Links" web part

Answer (score 1):

Add a column to the Links list. In this column enter the category for each link. Then create a list view that is grouped by the category.

Edit after clarification:

I see several possible approaches without involving code:

- use several list view web parts side by side, filtering only on the categories you want to display
- use a DVWP with a table structure and manipulate the XSL to display
  as desired
- use a DVWP with a nested list structure and use CSS to format the
  list output into a horzontal display

Comment: I tried the way you said but it doesn't give me a tabular view rather it groups the items like  a Tree view with "+" sign in front of each category (group by column). What I am looking for is I have added in my question.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you want to see? The text in the question does not tell much about grouping. Work it up in Word, formatting and all, then take a screenshot and upload that. Then at least we know what to aim for without guessing.

Comment: please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also try to work with the Content Query Web Part, depending on your exact requirement. CQWP allows you to display different styles (one for example is with a category, header and link).